# Python & XAMPP on Windows: how to?

Tags: python, windows, apache, xampp, mod-wsgi

I have installed on my Win7x64 Xampp and Python 2.7.

Now I'm trying to get the "power" of Python language... how can I do it?

I've tried with mod_python and mod_wsgi but the first one does not exist for my version of Python, and when I try to start Apache after installing wsgi it gives me an error

```
< Directory "\x93C:/wsgi_app\x94"> path is invalid
```

I added a space between < and 'directory' to make the string visible here.

So... Anyone knows if there is a little tutorial to install these features?

Or is anyone is kind enough to explain me step by step what shall I do?

Thanks and sorry if i'm not so able to explain me.

If you need something, please ask me.

Comment: Now it gives me "error 500" or "error 403" :(

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes you are right, mod_python won't work with Python 2.7. So mod_wsgi is the best option for you.

I would recommend AMPPS as python environment is by default enabled with mod_python and python 2.5. [AMPPS Website](http://www.ampps.com)

if you still want to continue,

Add this line in httpd.conf

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

Uncomment the line in httpd.conf

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Open vhost file httpd-vhosts.conf and add

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    <Directory "path/to/directory/in/which/wsgi_test.wsgi/is/present">
        Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        allow from All
    </Directory>
    ServerName 127.0.0.1
    ServerAlias 127.0.0.1
    WSGIScriptAlias /wsgi "path/to/wsgi_test.wsgi"
    DocumentRoot "path/to/htdocs"
    ErrorLog "path/to/log.err"
    CustomLog "path/to/log.log" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Add the following lines in wsgi_test.wsgi

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    output = 'Hello World!'

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]
```

Note : Don't make the test directory in htdocs. Because I haven't tried that yet. These steps worked for me in AMPPS. :)

Then access 127.0.0.1/wsgi in your favorite browser. You will see Hello World!.

If you don't see, follow [QuickConfigurationGuide](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide)

OR

You can add these lines in httpd.conf

```
<IfModule wsgi_module>
<Directory path/to/directory>
    Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    allow from All
</Directory>
WSGIScriptAlias /wsgi path/to/wsgi_test.wsgi
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Is the virtual host necessary? :) Thanks for the reply anyway :):)

Comment: No it isn't necessary. You can add these lines to httpd.conf too.
<IfModule wsgi_module>
<Directory path/to/directory>
Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        allow from All
</Directory>
WSGIScriptAlias /wsgi path/to/wsgi_test.wsgi
</IfModule>

Comment: Ok with AMPPS works now :) But now can i start python applications from my webserver? :)

Comment: If I try to start one of my python script the server gives me error 500 :(

Comment: But if I start a script, it works only 1 time :( and the wsgi_test.wsgi works everytime ... how can i make the scripts start?? :(

Comment: What kind of files can I start from my webserver? There is some specific language? Or some Python modules? :)

Comment: Well for Python scripts, you will have to read that scripts document to start also we must know the python language. you can find the tutorials to learn python from google.

Comment: I know python language but my scripts doesn't start on my webserver :)

Comment: On local with python idle these scripts starts :) if write l, for example, 'print "hello world"' it gives me error 500 :)

Comment: Hi, put the path of your script here.
WSGIScriptAlias /wsgi path/to/your_script.wsgi

Comment: but can I add only one script at a time? Cannot I select an entire folder? :)

Comment: You can select entire directory. Follow [link](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives)

Comment: it's important to note that "WSGIScriptAlias" defines what you type into the browser in order to navigate to the script.

Answer (score 15):

**WSGI is a lot better**, but at least I googled and tried to set it up for days without success. CGI is less efficient, but as most people use windows for development only, it makes little/no difference. It's super easy to set up!

**CGI method:**

1. In xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf look for this line: **AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
       .asp**. Modify it so it looks like this: **AddHandler cgi-script
       .cgi .pl .asp .py**
2. At the top of each Python script you create, set the path to your version of Python. For instance, if yours is in C:\Python27 write: #!/Python27/python
3. Put test **sample test code** in xampp\cgi-bin and access localhost/cgi-bin/your-file.py

**sample test code**(change commented python path according where you have it installed):

```
#!C:/Python27/python

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
print "<html><head><title>Hello World from Python</title></head><body>Hello World from a Python CGI Script</body></html>"
```

I've tested this in xampp 1.8.1 if something doesn't work read tihs:

source: http://elvenware.com/charlie/development/web/Python/Xampp.html