# Premature end of script headers: in basic python script

Tags: python, apache, xampp

Hi guys I am trying to follow http://elvenware.com/charlie/development/web/Python/Xampp.html to set up python with xampp . I am running xammp usb lite 1.77

following the directions here and on [Python & XAMPP on Windows: how to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8363247/python-xampp-on-windows-how-to),

I have created

```
#!F:/Python27/python

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
print "<html><head><title>Hello World from Python</title></head><body>Hello World from a Python CGI Script</body></html>
```

when I try to run it after placing it in the cgi-bin folder and running it like htp://localhost/cgi-bin/test.py I get:

```
Premature end of script headers: test.py
```

BTW an included htp://localhost/cgi-bin/cgi.cgi script works!!

Any idea what I can do to fix this?

Thank you in advance,

Bill

Comment: +1 to @sotapme. You should write this up as an answer. Notice that if you run this same script on the command line, it will raise a `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal` without even executing the first `print` statement. Which means no headers get printed out, which means you will get this error from `xampp`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no ending `"` on line 2 - unless it's  a mistake in copy/pasting

Comment: You fixed it. Sorry, I'm new to python - Bill

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with xampp.

The problem is in the `httpd.conf`. With xampp apache will be installed with another `httpd.conf` like the standalone install of apache.

Check your settings in the `httpd.conf` and change it.

Comment: It would help to provide the full paths of the multiple `httpd.conf` files as well as what setting you believe is wrong within the problematic file.